# .htaccess allow subfiles but not auto index or index.html

Tags: .htaccess, passwords

I have a sub-directory that I wan't to deny access using htaccess password protection with but allow all other files within this to be directly accessable, eg:

`www.mydomain.com/images` <- Password Protected

`www.mydomain.com/images/index.html` <- Password Protected

`www.mydomain.com/images/img1.png` <- Not Protected

Current .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpassword

<Files "index.html">
Require valid-user
</Files>
```

This currently password protects /images/index.html and allows me to access /images/img1.png

But it does deny access to /images but doesn't bring up the box to allow me to enter my details it just loads with 401 Unauthorized, how do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have these directives in `/images/.htaccess` to get your job done:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/images/(index\.html)?$" PROTECTED

AuthType Basic
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpassword
Require valid-user

Order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from env=PROTECTED
Satisfy any
```

Regex `^/images/(index\.php)?$` will set env var `PROTECTED` for `/images/` and `/images/index.html`.

Make sure to test with only these directives in `/images/.htaccess`

Comment: This didn't work at all, it actually stopped all of it from being protected. I even tried to modify it to be .html because I've a .html as my index and not .php

Comment: Check updated code. Keep **only these directives** in `/images/.htaccess` and test from a new browser. This is working perfectlyfine on my Apache.

Comment: Got it working, realised when I copied the code I pasted it with a spelling error. Thanks!